# Send base64 image data to controller using ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, canvas, html5-canvas, base64

```
        function takess(){
           html2canvas(document.querySelector("#figdiv")).then(canvas => {
                dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
                $.ajax({
                  type: "post",
                  url: "/savemarkupscreenshot",
                  data: { 
                     imgBase64: dataURL
                  }
                }).done(function(o) {
                  console.log(o);
                  $('#markupimage').val(o);
                  $('#markupform').submit();  
                });
            });
        };
```

this function works perfectly on local (it sends base64 data , converts it to image in controller , the controller returns the name of the image ).
But when deployed on live server it gives **net::ERR_TIMED_OUT**

Comment: Do you see the requests reaching the server ? If not check your network.
If the request reaches your server, check the return code or do some debugging ( print the request headers, etc)

Comment: @deepesh no the request doesnt reach the server. And there is no issue with my network as well

Answer (score 1):

**This seems like firewall issue.**

Change your server's firewall settings. Allow the port you are using

Example:

> sudo ufw allow 6001

For reference on how to setup firewall for UBUNTU

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04